How MAX_SAFE_INTEGER 2 ** 53 - 1
We Know in Javascript it uses the STD IEEE 754 Double precision and we know that the Mantissa Section is 52 bit and there is implicit 1 bit but is not stored
But if it isn't stored how it's actually we represent it because we can store 52 bit that 1 bit what we are using for ?

The short answer is that floating-point significands are required to be stored in a unique, normalized form.  For example, the decimal number 3.25 is stored as the binary fraction 0b1.101 x 2¹, not as 0b11.01 x 2⁰ or 0b110.1 x 2⁻¹ or 0b0.1101 x 2².  And the fun fact is that, in binary, in floating point, in normalized form, for a nonzero number, the digit to the left of the decimal point is always 1.  So you don't need to store it.  So you get the effect of 53 bits' worth of precision, even though you only explicitly store 52.

See any good description of IEEE-754 floating point, such as this Wikipedia page or this one, for more information.

@SteveSummit Thx I got it but i wanna know that a number is actually stored as 52 bit and the computer treats as 53 bit right ? without storing that extra leading bit

If the "significand" is, say, the 53 bits 1.0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101, then only the 52 bits 0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101 are stored.

It might help to work through an example showing every step.
Let us construct an IEEE-754 double-precision representation of the number 21.3125.
First, convert it to an ordinary binary fraction:
10101.01010

Next convert it to binary exponential notation:
10101.01010 × 2⁰

Next adjust the significand and exponent so that the significand is normalized:
1.010101010 × 2⁴

(What does "normalized" mean?  Simply that the part to the left of the decimal point is exactly 1, or stated another way, that the significand is in the range [1, 2).)
Next, to make things clear later on, pad the significand out to 53 full bits of precision:
1.0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 × 2⁴

(This obviously doesn't change the value at all.)
Before proceeding, there are two things we have to check: (1) Is the significand equal to 0 (this would only happen if our original number was 0.0), and (2) is the exponent outside of the range [-1022, 1023]?  In our case neither condition holds true, so we may proceed.
A floating-point number consists of three distinct parts: the sign, the significand, and the exponent.  In our case the sign is 'positive', the significand is 1.0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, and the exponent is 4.  And each of these parts needs to be encoded a little bit further before we are done.

A positive sign is represented by a single bit of 0.

The exponent is encoded by adding a constant bias of 1023 to it.  So 4 + 1023 is 1027, or 0x0403, or 0b10000000011 in binary.

The significand is encoded (this is the fun part!) by throwing away the leading "1.", leaving just the 52 fraction bits 0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.


Now assemble these three parts together, sign first, fraction bits last:
  0 10000000011 0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Finally jam all the bits together, and then, if you like, convert to hexadecimal to make it more compact:
  0 10000000011 0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
= 0100000000110101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
= 0100 0000 0011 0101 0101 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
=  4    0    3    5    5    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 
= 0x4035500000000000

To confirm that this has all worked, we can reverse the procedure:

Break the 64-bit value back up into the three parts 0, 10000000011, and 0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.
The sign bit is 0, so our eventual number will be positive, or +1.
The exponent field 10000000011 is 0x403, or 1027 in decimal.  Make sure it is not at its minimum possible value (0), or its maximum possible value (2047 or 0x7ff).  It is not, so proceed with steps 4–6.
Subtract the bias 1023 from 1027, yielding a true exponent of 4.
Prepend "1." to the fraction bits, giving 1.0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.
Finally, put it all together:

    +1 × 0b1.0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 × 2⁴

Now, 0b1.0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is 1.33203125, and 1.33203125 × 2⁴ is 1.33203125 × 16 which is 21.3125 which is the number we started with.  (Hooray!)
And the bottom line is that although the double precision format we've been working with does encode 53 significant bits of precision, we only "explicitly" stored the fraction bits 0101010100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, not the leading 1.  Although, as Eric has pointed out, the fact that the leading bit was 1 is encoded in a different way, by the fact that the exponent was in its normal range.  If the exponent had been at its minimum value, the leading bit would have been 0, not 1, and this is how it's possible to encode a value of 0.0.  (It also lets you handle subnormal numbers, but that's a topic for another day.)
Even when you work through it like this, I know, it still seems somehow magic that you can throw away the leading 1. and not store it.  How can that work?  The answer is simply that for every single value in the normal range (there are precisely 9,214,364,837,600,034,816 of them), they all start with "1.", so that leading 1 bit adds no information, it's redundant, you don't need to store it. You can remember it was there, and "add it back in" like we did in step 5 of my reconstruction, and you'll always get your original value back out.
There's some more discussion of this point at a former question Is it 52 or 53 bits of floating point precision?.

The leading bit of the significand is said to be “implicit,” but that is misleading. The leading bit is encoded in the bits that represent the floating-point field. It is in the “exponent” field, which actually encodes several things. Taking the 11 bits of the “exponent” field as a binary numeral E:

If E = 2047, the bits represent an infinity or a NaN (depending on the bits in the trailing significand field).
If 0 < E < 2047, the bits represent an exponent of E−1023 and a leading significand bit of 1.
If E = 0, the bits represent an exponent of −1022 and a leading significand bit of 0.

So the leading bit is not implicit; it is an explicit function of the “exponent” field.

@chux-ReinstateMonica: Thanks, fixed.

i know but is it actually stored like in memory ?

@YousefDawood No need for storing that in memory, the computer which decodes the binary value knows the 53rd bit is 1 for normalized numbers and 0 for denormals. For more details read my answer.

@YousefDawood: The exponent field bits are part of the bits that are stored in memory when a floating-point number is stored in memory, and those bits tell you what the leading bit of the significand is.

@YousefDawood You keep asking if they are "actually stored like that".  We have told you several times that indeed only 52 of the bits are conventionally stored, and that the 53rd bit is not conventionally stored.  Is there something you're still not understanding?

@YousefDawood This picture shows the layout clearly.  See also the pages IEEE 754 and Double-precision floating-point format.

I did understand but my confusion is if it stores a 52 bit why would i use a 53bit value in my code ?


How MAX_SAFE_INTEGER 253 - 1 ?

Besides the other answers, we can also look at the question, "How can JavaScript encode 53-bit integers in 52 bits?"  And the answer is, it doesn't; that would be an egregious violation of the pigeonhole principle.
It's true, JavaScript encodes all numbers using IEEE-754 double-precision floating point.  And, it's true, in this format, integers like 9007199254740991 are perfectly representable but would require 53 bits to represent in straight binary.  But they are not being "represented" entirely within the 52-bit IEEE-754 significand field; they are being represented as a full 64-bit double-precision floating-point value.  So there are plenty of bits available; there are no information-theoretical paradoxes.
To see what's going on, let's pick another value, like 1000000.  In binary it's 11110100001001000000.  But if you stored the value 1000000 in a JavaScript program, and used some kind of extraordinary electron microscope to inspect the bits that were actually stored in memory, you would not find that bit pattern 11110100001001000000.  Instead you'd find, in part, 11101000010010000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (note one fewer leading 1 bit, and a bunch of extra trailing 0 bits), and if you weren't careful you might think you had a number more like 8172669929259008.
But, no, if you looked elsewhere you'd find an exponent value of 19 (encoded as 0x412), and after restoring the leading 1 bit and the radix point you'd get 1.11101000010010000000000000000000000000000000000000000 × 219, which works out to, yes, exactly 1000000.  (See another answer for more details on how this kind of math works out.)
The bottom line is that a value like 1000000 (or, indeed, any value) is encoded using a combination of the 52-bit fraction field and the 11-bit exponent field.  (Also of course the sign bit, in case you're working with negative numbers.)  So you're not getting something for nothing.
